# How to prevent nested resolvers in some child states with angular-ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here is plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/wfIFA01kfG1zggsPo7Q9

I have one abstract parent state 'app' and two child states 'app.home' and 'app.signin'. Parent state has to resolve some asynchronous stuff.

**app.core**:

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('app', {
      url: '',
      abstract: true,

      // has to be resolved by any child state, except app.auth
      resolve: {
        Something: function($http) {
          // real delay
          return $http.get('http://httpbin.org/delay/5');
        }
      }
    });
```

**app.home**:

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('app.home', {
      url: '/home',
      views: {
        'main@' : {
          template: '<div>I am home page</div> <a ui-sref="app.signin">Sign in</a>'
        }
      }
    });
```

**app.signin**

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('app.signin', {
      url: '/',
      views: {
        'main@' : {
          template: '<div>I am signin page </div> <a ui-sref="app.home">Home page</a>'
        }
      }
    });
```

I want any child state require `Something` too, except `app.signin`. How can I do that?

---

Also worth to mention, I do not describe any resolvers at my child states. But they still wait till the parent is done, and I thought that (quote from [ui-router doc](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#what-do-child-states-inherit-from-parent-states)):

> The resolve keys MUST be injected into the child states if you want to
>   wait for the promises to be resolved before instantiating the
>   children.

And I dont know why child states still resolving parent`s dependency.

Comment: You could create another abstract state from which app.signin will depend. Have you tried that?

Comment: I thought about that. It may solve my problem, but I would like to leave the things as they are and change `app.signin` state somehow in order to be able ignore parent`s resolver.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the wiki documentation is incorrect... I do not believe that resolve keys must be injected.

Comment: I have found some relevant issues: [issue#868](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/868) and [issue#1761](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1761). There are some clarifications in them, but the problem still exists.

Comment: @RobsonGilli, I gave up. I am no longer looking for solution with single root state. I decided to divide my application on public and private parts as you suggested. So you may post your answer and I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the ideia is to create another abstract state from which app.signin will depend on. This plunker demonstrate that(fork from your plunker): http://plnkr.co/edit/kpfbylbBTVX8Erm5cgoF?p=preview

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('app.auth', [
      'app.core'
    ])
    .config(function ($stateProvider) {
      $stateProvider
      .state('app2', {
          url: '',
          abstract: true
        })
        .state('app2.signin', {
          url: '/',
          views: {
            'main@' : {
              template: '<div>I am signin page </div> <a ui-sref="app.home">Home page</a>'
            }
          }
        });
    });
})();
```